# Rows Value as Column and Get the Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `AreaTable` that has the following structure and data:

```
Username    Area    Counter
-----------------------------
Pravin  Vskp       1    
anil    Hyd        3    
Pravin  Chennai    3
Ang     Vskp       1    
anil    Vskp       3    
Immi    Chennai    3
```

Now I want the data to be displayed as:

```
        VSKP    HYD   CHENNAI   
Pravin    1      0      3   
Anil      3      3      0
Ang       1      0      0    
Immi      0      0      3
```

I tried with the query

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT username, area,counter
        FROM AreaTable) AS ET
PIVOT(MIN(counter) FOR username IN (area) AS PT
```

can you please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
 DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [UserName] NVARCHAR(128)
    ,[Area] NVARCHAR(128)
    ,[Counter] TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([UserName], [Area], [Counter])
VALUES   ('Pravin','Vskp',1)
        ,('anil','Hyd',3)    
        ,('Pravin','Chennai',3)
        ,('Ang','Vskp',1)    
        ,('anil','Vskp',3)   
        ,('Immi','Chennai',3)

SELECT [UserName]
      ,COALESCE([Vskp],0) AS [Vskp]
      ,COALESCE([Hyd],0) AS [Hyd]
      ,COALESCE([Chennai],0) AS [Chennai]
FROM @DataSource DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Counter]) FOR [Area] IN ([Vskp], [Hyd], [Chennai])
) PVT
```

The result of this query is

[image]

Note, in case the count of distinct values in the `[Area]` column vary, you should check how a dynamic pivot is make. There are plenty of answers in SO.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select username,[VSKP],[HYD],[CHENNAI] from
(select username,area,counter from @t) as src
pivot( 
min(Counter) for Area in([VSKP],[HYD],[CHENNAI])
) as pvt
```